# Update double? by referencing it in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, double, pass-by-reference

I have an array of double? and I want to update (set) some of their values. However it looks like I can’t do this. I tried to do it directly, then after some research tried the below, which also doesn’t update the original object (in this case `t2`). What am I missing? How can I update underlying objects that are contained in an array?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void tst(ref double? input, int mult)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        input = input * mult;
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        double? t1 = 1.1;
        double? t2 = 2.1;
        double? t3 = 3.1;
        double?[] ta = { t1, t2, t3 };
        // change value of t2
        tst(ref ta[1], 33);

        Console.WriteLine(t1);
        Console.WriteLine(t2); // I want this to be 69.3, but it’s still 2.1
        Console.WriteLine(t3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Value types are copied when you make a normal assignment - so when you call `double?[] ta = { t1, t2, t3 };` it is making a copy of `t2` and putting that in your array. It's not a reference to `t2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is as has been explained, the array you have is a copy of the variables value, not a copy of its memory location.

Here is a nonsensical example of how you can over come this issue, and also might help better understand whats going on by making an array of pointers (addresses in memory to your values)

- To get the address we can use `&`
- To get the value again we can prefix `*`
- To *Type* our pointers we can use `type*`
- `(IntPtr)(double*)` is just so we can display the address

**Code**

```
public unsafe static void tst(double* input, int multi)
{  
   Console.WriteLine("Make sure everything looks fine");
   Console.WriteLine($"Ptr: {(IntPtr)input}, Value: {*input}");

   // overwrite the location its pointing to
   *input *=  multi;

   Console.WriteLine($"Ptr: {(IntPtr)input}, Value: {*input}");    
}

private unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
   //Some numbers
   double t1 = 10;
   double t2 = 20;
   double t3 = 30;

   Console.WriteLine("Locations and values");
   Console.WriteLine($"Ptr: {(IntPtr)(double*)&t1}, Value: {t1}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Ptr: {(IntPtr)(double*)&t2}, Value: {t2}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Ptr: {(IntPtr)(double*)&t3}, Value: {t3}");

   // create an array that pointers to the memory location of my awesome numbers
   double*[] ta = { &t1, &t2, &t3 };

   // pass in the array an
   tst(ta[1], 324);
   Console.WriteLine("Double check the results");
   Console.WriteLine($"Ptr: {(IntPtr)(double*)&t1}, Value: {t1}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Ptr: {(IntPtr)(double*)&t2}, Value: {t2}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Ptr: {(IntPtr)(double*)&t3}, Value: {t3}");

}
```

**Ouput**

```
Locations and values
Ptr: 5239124, Value: 10
Ptr: 5239116, Value: 20
Ptr: 5239108, Value: 30
Make sure everything looks fine
Ptr: 5239116, Value: 20
Ptr: 5239116, Value: 6480
Double check the results
Ptr: 5239124, Value: 10
Ptr: 5239116, Value: 6480
Ptr: 5239108, Value: 30
```

Additional Resources

- [Pointer Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-conversions)
- [Pointer types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types)
- [Pointer Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-expressions)
- [How to: Obtain the Value of a Pointer Variable (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/how-to-obtain-the-value-of-a-pointer-variable)
- [How to: Obtain the Address of a Variable (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/how-to-obtain-the-address-of-a-variable)
- [How to access an array element with a pointer (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/how-to-access-an-array-element-with-a-pointer)
- [unsafe (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe)

**Update**

You could user an indexer

> Ok the context is that I have a class that (among other things)
>   contains 12 double? properties representing months of the year. Some
>   business logic determines at runtime which of them are to be updated
>   based on an incoming array of 12 values. So I had hoped to use an
>   array to drive this implementation in order to update their values,
>   rather than 12 separate test-and-conditionally-update blocks. –

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public int P1 { get; set; }
   public int P2 { get; set; }
   public int P3 { get; set; }
   public int P4 { get; set; }
   public int P5 { get; set; }

   public int this[int i]
   {
      get {
         switch (i)
         {
            case 0: return P1;
            case 1: return P2;
            case 2: return P3;
            case 4: return P5;
         }
      }
      set
      {
         switch (i)
         {
            case 0: P1 = value;  break;
            case 1: P2 = value; break;
            case 2: P3 = value;  break;
            case 4: P4 = value; break;
         }
      }
   }
}

...

SomeClass[2] // access like an array
```

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral - before I delve into the references (no pun intended), is there a safe solution to my problem, and/or a preferred approach for this general situation? I’m not across the implications of implementing something that is `unsafe`.

Comment: @sasfrog not through any direct means, you would have to create a class. Why do you want to do this, why is it important to change a local variable in an array?

Comment: Ok the context is that I have a class that (among other things) contains 12 double? properties representing months of the year. Some business logic determines at runtime which of them are to be updated based on an incoming array of 12 values. So I had hoped to use an array to drive this implementation in order to update their values, rather than 12 separate test-and-conditionally-update blocks.

Comment: @sasfrog updated with an indexer example, however, its kind of a *meh* solution

Comment: Thanks, I’ll play around with that idea. Introducing something `unsafe` just for this little case seems a bit hard-hitting. Ta

Comment: OK @TheGeneral this solved the issue I had in terms of implementing something, but I agree it's pretty crappy to have to have an indexer just to address objects.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
double?[] ta = { t1, t2, t3 };
```

`ta` is a new array of double using `t1`,`t2`,`t3` values (not their reference). and `ta[1]` is not same as `t2`,  and just have the same value.
so passing `ta[1]` by ref will change the `ta[1]` value, but not `t2` value (that just its value has been copied to `ta`). so if you have a look at `ta[1]` value it should be changed to 69.3

Comment: Thanks for this. You've explained well what's happening, but your answer doesn't actually tell me how I can update `t2`, which is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

you must call tst function for both ta[2] and ta[3] before print  Console.WriteLine

```
tst(ref ta[1], 33);
tst(ref ta[2], 33);
tst(ref ta[3], 33);

Console.WriteLine(ta[1]);
Console.WriteLine(ta[2]);
Console.WriteLine(ta[3]);
```

Console.WriteLine must be print **ta[i]**, because it's value referenced in tst function